# Get Prefab From Gameobject in Editor Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a script that will be called from ContextMenu in Editor Mode to modify gameobjects that are located inside a prefab. Basically, I want to modify a prefab.

But when I try to get a prefab out of this gameobject it does not work:

```
GameObject prefab = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabInstanceHandle(test_gameobj) as GameObject;
Debug.Log("prefab: " + prefab);
```

Debug.Log prints this in console:

[image]

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPrefabInstanceHandle.html)? I'm not sure about exactly what you want to do and I've never used it but it seems to be decently described what the function does here.